# selenium send_keys() on a site did not recognise Cyrillic input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, cyrillic

I'm a newbie and stack at the beginning of Big journey
My problem is:

- I've got a site, where I try to input information in Cyrillic
- when I input information manually everything is fine
- even if I input information using selenium, chrome in ENG, everything is fine
- but in Cyrillic through selenium nothing happened
- Option '--lang=ru' did not help
- new profile in chrome with indication of Lang in preferences samesh..t - nothing happened

PS I test other site through selenium, chrome, Cyrillic working fine.

Please help me

```
opt= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=...")
opt.add_argument(r'--profile-directory= "..."')
chrome_locale = 'RU'
opt.add_argument("--lang={}".format(chrome_locale))
opt.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.5249.119 Safari/537.36")
opt.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)

DRIVER = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv, options=opt)
DRIVER.implicitly_wait(0.5)
url = 'my_site'
DRIVER.get(url)

# authentification

##### input information

print('# поиск DEBTS')
_input = DRIVER.find_element(By.XPATH, '...')
_input.click()
_input.send_keys('иванов')
time.sleep(5)
_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Please share all your code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I just realised - how it's possible to be more specific ? I did mention programme, I did mentione function, I did mention exact point of Error